# Get the total price of a registration properly to use that total price in a credit card charge

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have a FrontendController that has the show() method that returns the user to the conference details page with the available tickets for the conference:

```
class FrontEndController extends Controller
    public function show($id, $slug){
            $conf = Conference::where('id', $id)->first();
            $ticketTypes = TicketType::where('conference_id', $conf->id)->get();
            ...
            return view('conferences.show')->with('conference',$conf)->with('ticket_types', $ticketTypes);
    }
}
```

Then in the conference details page (show.blade.php) the user can select the tickets that he wants with:

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    @foreach($ticket_types as $ttype)
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
            <div class="w-100 text-truncate">
                <span>{{$ttype->name}}</span>
            </div>
            <select class="custom-select form-control" name="ttypes[{{ $ttype->name }}]">
                <option selected></option>
                @for ($i = $ttype->min_participants; $i <= $ttype-> max_participants; $i++)
                    <option value="{{ $i }}">{{ $i }}</option>
                @endfor
            </select>
        </li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
     <input type="submit" class="float-right btn btn-primary" value="Next" />
```

Then when the user clicks in "Next"the request goes to the RegistrationController storeQuantities() method that stores info about the selected tickets by the user in the session and redirects the user to the registration page (registration.blade.php):

```
class RegistrationController extends Controller
{
public function storeQuantities(Request $request, $id, $slug = null){
    $ttypeQuantities = $request->get('ttypes');
    ...
    $selectedRtypes[$ttype->name]['quantity'] = $quantity;
    $selectedRtypes[$ttype->name]['price'] = $price;
    $selectedRtypes[$ttype->name]['subtotal'] = $price * $quantity;
    $total+=  $selectedRtypes[$ttype->name]['subtotal'];
    $selectedRtypes[$ttype->name]['total'] = $total;
    ...

    Session::put('selectedRtypes', $selectedRtypes);
    ...
    return redirect(route('conferences.registration',['id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug]));
    }
}
```

In the registration.blade.php I have a multistep form with 3 steps. All steps are on the same page. The step1 is to collect info about the user that is doing the registration, the step 2 is for the user select the payment method, step 3 is the payment.

So step1 has a form like:

```
<div>
    <form method="post" id="step1form" action="">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <!-- fields of the step 1-->
        <input type="submit" href="#step2" id="goToStep2" class="btn next-step" value="Go to step 2"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

When "go to step 2" is clicked the code goes to the RegistrationController storeUserInfo() using an ajax request, if the storeUserInfo() returns code 200 the user goes to step 2 using jQuery.

So, if code 200 is returned user is in the step2form:

```
<div>
    <form method="post" id="step2form" action="">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <!-- fields of the step 2-->
         <input type="submit" href="#step3" id="goToStep3" class="btn next-step" value="Go to step 3"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

In the step3 the user selects a payment method and click "go to step 3" the code goes through an ajax request to RegistrationController `storePaymentMethods()` to validate the info introduced by the user in step 2 if is returned the code 200 the user goes to the step 3.

The step3 has this form below that has a button "Pay" that shows a Stripe modal:

```
<form action="{{ route('registration.charge') }}" method="post" id="paymentForm">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" id="stripeToken"/>
        <input type="submit" href="" id="payment" class="btn btn-primary float-right"
               value="Pay"/>
    </form>
```

Charge method to handle the Stripe charge:

```
public function charge(Request $request)
    {
        Stripe::setApiKey(config('services.stripe.secret'));
        $source = $request->stripeToken;
        Charge::create([
            'currency' => 'eur',
            'description' => 'Example charge',
            'amount' => 2500,
            'source' => $source,
        ]);
    }
```

My doubt is how to set in amount instead of a static value '2500' insert the correct total price of the registration. And also when the Stripe modal appears I want to show the total price of the registration in Stripe modal button. Do you know how to achieve that?

Inside the `charge()` maybe a correct approah can be get the the value from the session like:

```
$selectedRtypes =  Session::get('selectedRtypes');
$amount = (collect($selectedRtypes)->first()['total']) * 100;
```

But do you know how to set the total value also in Stripe button? In the amount of the `stripe.open`.

Stripe code:

```
  let stripe = StripeCheckout.configure({
        key: "{{config('services.stripe.key')}}",
        image: "",
        locale: "auto",
        token: (token) => {
            document.querySelector('#stripeToken').value = token.id;
            document.querySelector('#paymentForm').submit();
        }
    });

    document.getElementById('payment').addEventListener('click', function(e){

        stripe.open({
            name: 'test',
            description: 'test',
            amount: 1000
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: You've already got `$selectedRtypes` in the session just use it in the blade like `$selectedRtypes[whatever]['total']`